# WSO2 Identity Server OAuth2 access token request redirects to login page

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to send a request to `https://{identity-server}:9443/oauth2/token`. And the request is redirected to Location: `https://{identity-server}:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp`. The version I'm using is IS 5.7.0 and deployed on Kubernetes as a clustered setup.

Comment: Can you show your curl request and response?

Comment: curl request : `curl -X POST  https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -I 'grant_type=password&username=***&password=***&client_id=*******&client_secret=*****&scope=bearer' -k`

Comment: response : `HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=55AB7963F5AAD09AE730890045E7CC2D; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: requestedURI=../../oauth2/token; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2020 07:27:00 GMT
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the authorization header in the request. That's why you are getting redirected to the login page.

Try to provide the authorization header like this

```
Authorization: Basic [Base64encode(Client-ID>:<ClientSecret>)]
```

Final request should be similar to this

```
curl -X POST \
  https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Zkd2ZlhiQ05VeUFmd2ltQW9HSWYycXZDakdFYTpFb1NOWDdHNFQ2NGZjcVFyZTVIX2NPR01CS2Nh' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=bearer'
```

Comment: The above request should work if you pass the authorization header correctly. Can you please share a screenshot of your service provider along with the new curl request and response.

Comment: request : 
`curl -X POST https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token -H 'authorization: Basic *****' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'postman-token: ****' \
  -d 'grant_type=password&username=***&password=***&client_id=****&client_secret=****' `

service provider : https://i.imgur.com/y3yZcJ6.png
oauth2 config : https://i.imgur.com/beIqH6C.png

Comment: Can you remove the client_id and client_secret from the body and try?